# Ошибка в RecyclerView при вызове notifyItemRemoved(position)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, исключения

Ошибка появляется когда удаляю `item` из 0 позиции, если из других позиций удалять, то все ок.
Прогуглил, прочитал что это ошибка в самом `RecyclerView`. Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой? Что можно сделать в общем?

```
01-13 06:57:16.375 7314-7314/com.example.user.digital E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.user.digital, PID: 7314
                                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:-1).state:4 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{47bd973 VFEDH.... .F....ID 0,0-1440,2448 #7f0800ac app:id/recycler_view_for_my_list}, adapter:com.example.user.digital.adapter.MyListAdapter@33b7aaf, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@20ebebc, context:com.example.user.digital.MyListActivity@8f1f8ed
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5628)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:618)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3644)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3408)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

UPD:

```
public abstract class SwipeControllerActions {

    public void onRightClicked(int position) {
        removeItem(position);
    }
}
```

В адаптере

```
private void removeItem(int position) {

    Item item = dataList.get(position);
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask(item);
    myTask.execute();
    dataList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

В ItemTouchHelper

```
private void setTouchUpListener(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final float dX, final float dY, final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    SwipeController.super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0F, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    setItemsClickable(recyclerView, true);
                    swipeBack = false;

                    if (buttonsActions != null && buttonInstance != null && buttonInstance.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) {
                            buttonsActions.onRightClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    }
                    buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
                    currentItemViewHolder = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Вроде это сделано специально, но я точно не помню) Просто удаляйте с 1 позиции, делов то.

Comment: Пробовал такое, удаляется позиция 1, а не 0)

Comment: Я не помню, сети ли у RV итератор по элементам. Если есть, то попробуйте через него.

Comment: Хотя я забыл. Всеми данными адаптер управляет. Смотрите его методы или реализуйте свой.

Comment: Интересно с чем это связано, метод `remove` вызываю в `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` может в этом причина?

Comment: Конечно же желательно вызывать без посредников. + Выложите тогда код, где удаляете элемент.

Comment: Выкинул код, весь класс CallBack выкладывать не стал.

Comment: Во-первых, ошибка в строчке `dataList.remove(position)`? Во-вторых, есть метод notifydatasetchange, который уведомляет view, для перерисовки (Не уверен, что обязательно). Из ошибки видно, что RV пытается перерисоваться, но выходит за границы. Хмм. Чего-то не хватает.

Comment: ‘dataList.remove(position)’ в чем ошибка? Удалили из листа, обновил адаптер.

Comment: На счёт remove - это старые мысли) Я всегда вызывал метод `super.notifyDataSetChanged()` в адаптере и позже уведомлял фрагмент например. Вызов`notifyItemRemoved` вижу первый раз - это кастомный объект или стандартный интерфейс? Проверьте метод `getCount` и пройдитесь отладчиком.

Comment: Стандартный, и по моему рекомендуется для этих целей, могу ошибаться конечно. Он с анимацией удаляет.

Comment: Последнее предположение: может вызывать метод `notifyItemRemove` перед ударением элемента?

Comment: [Посмотрите сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189371/using-notifyitemremoved-or-notifydatasetchanged-with-recyclerview-in-android), там про удаление элементов - 3 ответ.

Comment: Тоже делал, ситуацию не меняет. Кстати notifyDataSetChanged() баг фиксит, но я не особо хочу его использовать. Ладно буду разбираться.

Comment: notifyItemRangeChange тоже использовал после notifyItemRemoved, и тоже баг присутствует.

Comment: ну вот про эту проблему [писали на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/255397/)/ В одном из багтреков по проблеме называют причину, что это происходит из-за того, что адаптер не получает уведомления о изменении данных и соответственно кидает экзепшен, потому что расхождение в индексах получается. в общем это баг и пока, как я понял, он не исправлен, поэтому решения костылями (как в статье, например)

Comment: Ясно, значит буду костыли лепить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, в моем случае я удалил строку `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` и все корректно заработало.

Comment: этот метод устанавливается в `true` только для данных, которые действительно имеют уникальный идентификатор (как выборка из БД и тп.) и этот идентификатор корректно возвращается (переопределен метод `getItemId()`), иначе `RecyclerView` начинает "чудить". Вот [статья](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/material-part-7/), в которой объясняется, как это работает и зачем нужно.

Comment: Я его и ставил изначально для того, что бы иметь уникальные id. Потом нашёл другой подход и просто забыл его убрать.